# Parsing key value pairs using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I've a scenario where I have to capture key value pairs from a string where the key cannot contain spaces. Following are the constraints that apply for values:

1. They can contain spaces when delimited with single or double quotes.
2. They can contain single quotes when delimited with double quotes.
3. They can contain double quotes when delimited with single quotes.
4. Key value pairs are separated using spaces/tabs.

Single string that contains all key/value pairs to extract (using / for string delimiters for simplicity):

```
/abc="hello how are you" xyz="I'm good. How are you?" pqr='Using " double quotes'/
```

I would like to parse the above string and extract the name/value pairs:

1. `abc="hello how are you"`
2. `xyz="I'm good. How are you?"`
3. `pqr='Using " double quotes'`

Comment: Tried anything to solve it?

Comment: @anubhava, yes. i tried few things before posting it here. my case contains lot of constraints other than what I've posted here. i could not get this right as i'm not so good at it.

Comment: In that case @Kerwin's answer should work.

Comment: yeah. it helped for the question i posted.

Answer (score 3):

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tM3cE9/1)

```
(\w+)=(['"])((?!\2).+?)\2
```

`$1` is key ,
`$3` is value

```
while(match.find()){
//save it to map
}
```